# Terminal not moving to front when opened

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, settings, atom

I'm using the Atom text editor, and I've installed the Gpp compiler package. When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to compile and run a program, Atom opens a gnome terminal showing the output of my program, however this terminal opens *behind* the atom text editor. How can I fix this? I want the terminal to automatically pop up in front of the atom text editor when run.

Comment: make sure that your atom window isn't set to **Always on top**, just saying

Comment: I did; that wasn't the problem

Comment: I'm afraid, that's the extent of my knowledge about your problem.